# How do I clear all options in a dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, html-select

My code works in IE but breaks in Safari, Firefox, and Opera. (big surprise)

```
document.getElementById("DropList").options.length=0;
```

After searching, I've learned that it's the `length=0` that it doesn't like.
I've tried `...options=null` and `var clear=0; ...length=clear` with the same result.

I am doing this to multiple objects at a time, so I am looking for some lightweight JS code.

Comment: To **destroy** all options (!?), and about reset the browser's history of selected options after refresh page, to use the HTML's  `<option selected>`??  (google put us here but it is not here)... See [document.getElementById("form1").reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) real solution.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the following to clear all the elements.

```
var select = document.getElementById("DropList");
var length = select.options.length;
for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  select.options[i] = null;
}
```

Comment: It still crashed when i try the above JS...probably some other conflicting code.

I hadn't considered jQuery. I think that's just what I'm looking for...but maybe to remove the whole option child:
    $("select[id$=DropList] > option").remove();

Comment: MooTools also has `empty()`, so you would do `$("DropList").empty();`

Comment: This seems like a bad idea - setting the items to null is not the same as removing them.

Comment: It also dosen't work as excpected. When i use that code it leaves one object in dropdown.

Comment: This code might crash. The safest way to run the loop in reverse.

Comment: Check the other answers for a better way to do this.

Comment: This code will fail as we are trying to remove the options from index 0. The for loop should be run in reverse order starting from the (length-1) to 0.

Comment: This is a WRONG IMPLEMENTATION AND SHOULD NOT BE THE ANSWER. since you are clearing the array the loop should run from (length-1) to 0.

Comment: right, it should be rather: for (i = length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {

Comment: This answer is wrong. I have used it without thinking and noticed that the select box didn't empty. Only half. Called again. Again only half. I tried to post an edit to correct the code but it was rejected. This answer is wrong. What to do?

Comment: select.options.length = 0 will do

Answer (score 382):

To remove the options of an HTML element of [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), you can utilize the [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove) method:

```
function removeOptions(selectElement) {
   var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
   for(i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
      selectElement.remove(i);
   }
}

// using the function:
removeOptions(document.getElementById('DropList'));
```

It's important to remove the [`options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options) backwards; as the `remove()` method rearranges the `options` collection. This way, it's guaranteed that the element to be removed still exists!

Comment: cheers for that @Fabiano, this actually removes the items as opposed to other suggestions.

Comment: the key here is the backwards traversal of the selectbox.options I think....this solution failed when I tried forwards traversal

Comment: Yes, it will fail because the remove() method will rearrange the array. Doing it backwards will guarantee that the element to be removed will exist.

Comment: Adding selectbox.options.length = 0; in the end of definition might make it perfect in all browsers.

Comment: Simple code is while(selectEl.options.length) selectEl.options.remove(0)

Comment: One more option is `selectEl.innerHTML = "";`

Answer (score 182):

If you wish to have a lightweight script, then go for jQuery. 
In jQuery, the solution for removing all options will be like:

```
$("#droplist").empty();
```

Comment: I'd argue that the very act of adding jQuery is the opposite of "lightweight" when `for (a in select.options) { select.options.remove(0); }` does the work just fine.

Comment: It depends on the context. In a web application, the readability a hundred lines of `$("#droplist").empty();` type code compared to thousands of lines of vanilla JS make it well worth the addition of jQuery.
If we're talking markup/cosmetics for a simple webpage, you're 100% correct.

Comment: @AdamIngmansson I find it puzzling when people denigrate the use of JQuery. I'd use a method like this on the assumption that the engineers behind JQ have done all sorts of tests to find the best, fastest and above all most reliable means of doing a given (utility) task.  The point of JQ (or any good library) is to take on the mundane tasks so you can concentrate on the interesting things.

Comment: @mikerodent I have no doubt that the function itself is of top quality and performance. But loading a 86kb (the compressed lib of version 3.2.1) file just for that little function is not 'lightweight' :) Of course, if you have use of many of the other functionality, the it will be worth using jQuery. It's a very good library

Comment: @AdamIngmansson Fair enough! But I take it you're aware that the JQ min.js file is used so often it is very often found in a browser's cache. To such an extent that there's probably a good argument for saying "always use JQ and regard NOT using it as part of an optimisation stage, IF this really proves necessary".  It may possibly indeed prove necessary in certain contexts (phone apps, etc.) ... this is beyond my paltry JS knowledge.

Comment: Since I use jQuery in pretty much every JS project I've ever built, this was my go-to one-line answer.

Answer (score 149):

Probably, not the cleanest solution, but it is definitely simpler than removing one-by-one:

```
document.getElementById("DropList").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: I usually avoid innertHTML like the plague. But this makes things so much simpler that I actually like it.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Not sure why is doesn't clear the select options this way.

Comment: @MikaelL, it's useful if you add what browser it happens in. And its version, if you can remember.

Answer (score 98):

This is the best way :

```
function (comboBox) {
    while (comboBox.options.length > 0) {                
        comboBox.remove(0);
    }        
}
```

Comment: This saved me today, because the 'for() { selectbox.remove()}' mechanism somehow doesn't clear all the options. Thanks.

Comment: slightly shorter as `while (comboBox.options.length) comboBox.remove(0);`

Comment: definitely the cleanest solution

Answer (score 67):

I'd like to point out that the problem in the original question is not relevant today anymore. And there is even shorter version of that solution:

```
selectElement.length = 0;
```

I've tested that both versions work in Firefox 52, Chrome 49, Opera 36, Safari 5.1, IE 11, Edge 18, latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Samsung Internet and UC Browser on Android, Safari on iPhone 6S, Android 4.2.2 stock browser. I think it is safe to conclude that it's absolutely compatible with whatever device there is right now, so I recommend this approach.

Comment: Well done ! a more compliant version may be `selectElement.options.length = 0;`. for reference: [HTMLOptionsCollection length properties @ MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection#length). Your solution is probably the best one :D

Answer (score 52):

This is a short way:

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').innerText = null;
```

One line, no for, no JQuery, simple.

Comment: Not the shortest, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55897038/3075942) below.

Comment: From other answers, setting the length to zero crashed IE11. This answer worked for me.

Answer (score 31):

This is a bit modern and pure JavaScript

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#selectId option').forEach(option => option.remove())
```

Comment: Fastest code. For testing try to remove about 250000 options

Comment: why do you want to insert 250000 options into a select?

Comment: @Subliminal Hash, maybe to benchmark this solution and assert that this is the fastest solution?

Answer (score 19):

```
function removeOptions(obj) {
    while (obj.options.length) {
        obj.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is the only one which works for me. Iceweasel 10.0.12 and Chrome 26.

Answer (score 9):

Note that a select can have both
- optgroup &
- options collection
 as its children.

So,

Method #1

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById('myselectid');
selectElement.innerHTML = '';
```

Method #2

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById('myselectid');
selectElement.textContent = '';
```

I tested, both work on Chrome.
I like the simpler, the old fashioned, method #1.

Comment: This is the best answer. Also, if you already have a jquery reference to the select: `$select.html('')`

Comment: thank you. I believe this is what most people are looking for

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
document.getElementsByTagName("Option").length=0
```

Or maybe look into the removeChild() function.

Or if you use jQuery framework.

```
$("DropList Option").each(function(){$(this).remove();});
```

Answer (score 7):

with **PrototypeJS** :

```
$('yourSelect').select('option').invoke('remove');
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using JQuery and your select control has ID "DropList" you can remove its options doing this way:

```
$('#DropList option').remove();
```

Actually it works for me with any option list, like datalist.

Hope it helps.

Comment: A good answer should contain more detail than this. The reader may have no idea that you probably mean jQuery.

Comment: @Mifeet if the user has no idea what JQuery means here, he/she should change career

Answer (score 5):

Using JQuery is a prettier, shorter & smarter way to do it!

```
$('#selection_box_id').empty();
```

Comment: This is really just a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364493/how-do-i-clear-all-options-in-a-dropdown-box/3364721#3364721).

Answer (score 5):

For Vanilla JavaScript there is simple and elegant way to do this:

```
for(var o of document.querySelectorAll('#DropList > option')) {
  o.remove()
}
```

Comment: If you're able to use `for..of`, why not use `const` instead of `var`?

Answer (score 3):

Go reverse. Reason is size decreases after each remove.

```
for (i = (len-1); i > -1; i--) {
    document.getElementById("elementId").remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that is the best sol. is

```
 $("#myselectid").html('');
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be used to clear options:

```js
function clearDropDown(){
  var select = document.getElementById("DropList"),
      length = select.options.length;
  while(length--){
    select.remove(length);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="DropList" >
  <option>option_1</option>
  <option>option_2</option>
  <option>option_3</option>
  <option>option_4</option>
  <option>option_5</option>
</select>
<button onclick="clearDropDown()">clear list</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

The items should be removed in reverse, otherwise it will cause an error. Also, I do not recommended simply setting the values to `null`, as that may cause unexpected behaviour.

```
var select = document.getElementById("myselect");
for (var i = select.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    select.remove(i);
```

Or if you prefer, you can make it a function:

```
function clearOptions(id)
{
    var select = document.getElementById(id);
    for (var i = select.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
        select.remove(i);
}
clearOptions("myselect");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var select = document.getElementById("DropList");
var length = select.options.length;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  select.options[i].remove();
}
```

Hope, this code will helps you

Answer (score 3):

WOW you guys really like complicating things

```
  document.getElementById('idOfSelect').options.length = 0;
```

OR

```
  document.getElementById('idOfSelect').innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var select = document.getElementById('/*id attribute of your select here*/');
for (var option in select){
    select.remove(option);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answer's code need a slight change to remove the list complete, please check this piece of code.

```
var select = document.getElementById("DropList");
var length = select.options.length;
for (i = 0; i < length;) {
  select.options[i] = null;
  length = select.options.length;
}
```

refresh the length and it will remove all the data from drop down list. 
Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Nice addition - was stumped for a moment as to why it wasn't removing all of the options each time.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solutions are the best, so You just need:

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');
while (list.firstChild) {
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
}
```

```html
<select id="list">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var opt of document.querySelectorAll('#DropList option'))
{ 
  opt.remove();
}
```

This solution works with optgroups also.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(document.getElementById("DropList").childNodes.length>0) 
{
    document.getElementById("DropList").removeChild(document.getElementById("DropList").childNodes[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to support IE and you have more than 100 items in your select list, I strongly recommend you consider replacing the select with a function like so:

```
function clearOptions(select) {
    var selectParentNode = select.parentNode;
    var newSelect = select.cloneNode(false); // Make a shallow copy
    selectParentNode.replaceChild(newSelect, select);
    return newSelect;
}
```

The select parameter should be the element either from a jquery selector or document.getElementBy call.  The only downside to this is that you lose events you had wired up to the select, but you can easily reattach them as it is returned back out of the function.  I was working with a select that had ~3k items and it would take 4 seconds on IE9 to clear the select so I could update it with the new content.  Nearly instant doing it this way.

Comment: You can find more info here: http://www.somacon.com/p542.php and more simple way: ```$('#selectbox').replaceWith($('#selectbox')[0].cloneNode(false));```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#droplist").find('select').val('default');
```

You can also do this to change the dropdown list goes to default. Make sure to add default in your select dropdown list like this.

```
"<option value="default">Select option</option>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fastest solution:

```
document.getElementById("DropList").replaceChildren()
```

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<select multiple="" class="form-select courses" name="courses">
   <option>.....</option>
   ....
</select>
```

JS

```
function ClearOptions() {
   var courseSelect = document.querySelector(".courses");

   while (courseSelect.childNodes[0] != null) {
       courseSelect.childNodes[0].remove();
   }
}
```

Since we are manipulating the array we are using, the index will change with each deletion. Therefore, conditions such as i > 0 do not work correctly. In this case, it would be best to continue the deletion process one by one until there are no Elements left.

Answer (score -1):

Today I was facing same problem, I did as below while reloading select box. (In Plain JS)

```
        var select = document.getElementById("item");
        select.options.length = 0;
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = 0;
        opt.innerHTML = "Select Item ...";
        opt.selected = "selected";
        select.appendChild(opt);


       for (var key in lands) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = lands[key].id;
            opt.innerHTML = lands[key].surveyNo;
            select.appendChild(opt);

        }
```