# How to remove all options from a dropdown using jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have a dropdown as seen below:

```
<select id="models" onchange="removeElements()">
            <option id = "remove" value="0">R8</option>
            <option id = "remove" value="1">Quattro</option>
            <option id = "remove" value="2">A6 hatchback</option>
</select>
```

How would I create the script `removeElements()` that would remove all of the options within the select?

Comment: You understand that id section is meant to have a unique name, not as your option tags have.

Comment: Repeated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364493/how-do-i-clear-all-options-in-a-dropdown-box

Comment: Plain JS: `document.getElementById('models').length = 0` does it for me. If you already have a reference to the select, then `select.length = 0` (see [HTML5 section 4.10.7](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-select-length)).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You didn't say on which event.Just use below on your event listener.Or in your page load

```
$('#models').empty()
```

Then to repopulate

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("YourAction","YourController")',function(data){
 var dropdown=$('#models');
dropdown.empty();  
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    dropdown.append(
        $('<option>', {
            value: item.valueField,
            text: item.DisplayField
        }, '</option>'))
      }
     )});
```

Comment: could I then repopulate the models select after running this method?

Comment: I need to empty the contents on change and repopulate the dropdown

Comment: no after I cleat the select box I aim to make an ajax call and then repopulate the dropdown

Comment: ok thankyou - I am having an issue even triggering the function onchange

Comment: what if you just wanted to remove a couple of options from the dropdown conditionally. For example a dropdown of times throughout the day, no times before current time are shown.

Comment: @AkinHwan why dont you do this from server side

Answer (score 13):

You can either use [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) on option elements:

> .remove() : Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
 $('#models option').remove(); or $('#models').remove('option');
```

or use [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) on select:

> .empty() : Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
 $('#models').empty();
```

however to repopulate deleted options, you need to store the option while deleting.

You can also achieve the same using show/hide:

```
$("#models option").hide();
```

and later on to show them:

```
$("#models option").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone using JavaScript (as opposed to JQuery), might like to try this solution, where 'models' is the ID of the select field containing the list :-

```
var DDlist = document.getElementById("models");
while(DDlist.length>0){DDlist.remove(0);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeElements(){
  $('#models').html('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function removeElements(){
    $('#models').html("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case .empty() doesn't work for you, which is for me

```
function SetDropDownToEmpty() 
{           
$('#dropdown').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="0"></option>');
$("#dropdown").trigger("liszt:updated");          
}

$(document).ready(
SetDropDownToEmpty() ;
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other approach for Vanilla JavaScript:

```
for(var o of document.querySelectorAll('#models > option')) {
  o.remove()
}
```