# How to show Dropdownlist by another Dropdownlist using Array

Tags: javascript, magento, drop-down-menu

Sorry because I ask a stupid question. But I have lacked the knowledge about this. Can someone help me.

My "big boy" ask me to do the website by HTML only (not USE DATABASE), but he want me to make the Product Page to show the product. (Products are not many)

I have 2 inputs  to choose.
1. Style of product
2. Product list (depend on Style of product)
=> when we choose style the list of product will be list as condition.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SelectBoxOptions</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var  arrayStyle = ["AAAAAAAAAA","BBBBBBBBBB","CCCCCCCCCC","DDDDDDDDDD","EEEEEEEEEE"];
    var  arrayProduct_0 = ["No Data"];
    var  arrayProduct_1 = ["1111111111","1222222222","1333333333","1444444444"];
    var  arrayProduct_2 = ["2111111111","2222222222","2333333333","2444444444"];
    var  arrayProduct_3 = ["3111111111","3222222222","3333333333","3444444444"];
    var  arrayProduct_4 = ["4111111111","4222222222","4333333333","4444444444"];

    window.onload = function createElement()
    {
        var style = document.getElementById("pro_style");

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayStyle.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value",[i]);
            option.text = arrayStyle[i];
            style.appendChild(option);
        }
    }

    function changeProbyStyle(id)
    {
        var aaa = id;
        //alert(aaa);
        switch (id)
        {
        case "0":
            //alert("So 0");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_0);
            break;
        case "1":
            //alert("So 1");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_1);
            break;
        case "2":
            //alert("So 2");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_2);
            break;
        case "3":
            //alert("So 3");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_3);
            break;
        case "4":
            //alert("So 4");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_4);
            break;
        }
    }

    function setPro(arr)
    {
        bbb=arr;
        //alert(bbb);
        var name = document.getElementById("pro_name");

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value",[i]);
            option.text = arr[i];
            name.appendChild(option);
        }

    }

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form class="wrapper-dropdown">
        <h2>Product Style</h2>
            <select id="pro_style" onChange="changeProbyStyle(this.value);">
            </select>
        <h2>Product Name</h2>
            <select id="pro_name">
            </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For this example. When I choose `List 1 = "BBBBBBBBBB"`, List 2 will be `["1111111111","1222222222","1333333333","1444444444"] => 4 products`

And I choose`List 1 AGAIN = CCCCCCCCCC`. List 2 will be `["1111111111","1333333333","2111111111","2222222222","2333333333","2444444444"]; => 6 products`

I don't want it be....I want it JUST SHOW 4 products as List 1 was chose. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Thank for all.

**SOLUTION** 
Thank for give me the suggestion. I have found and tried much but I don't get it. Now everything is ok.
The solution for this is add do function like this to remove by "loop for" for the selectors.

```
function removeOptions(selectbox)
{
    var i;
    for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
}
//using the function:

removeOptions(document.getElementById("pro_name"));
```

And my completed code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SelectBoxOptions</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var  arrayStyle = ["AAAAAAAAAA","BBBBBBBBBB","CCCCCCCCCC","DDDDDDDDDD","EEEEEEEEEE"];
    var  arrayProduct_0 = ["No Data"];
    var  arrayProduct_1 = ["1111111111","1222222222","1333333333","1444444444"];
    var  arrayProduct_2 = ["2111111111","2222222222","2333333333","2444444444"];
    var  arrayProduct_3 = ["3111111111","3222222222","3333333333","3444444444"];
    var  arrayProduct_4 = ["4111111111","4222222222","4333333333","4444444444"];

    window.onload = function createElement()
    {
        var style = document.getElementById("pro_style");

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayStyle.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value",[i]);
            option.text = arrayStyle[i];
            style.appendChild(option);
        }
    }

    function changeProbyStyle(id)
    {
        var aaa = id;
        //alert(aaa);
        switch (id)
        {
        case "0":
            //alert("So 0");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_0);
            break;
        case "1":
            //alert("So 1");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_1);
            break;
        case "2":
            //alert("So 2");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_2);
            break;
        case "3":
            //alert("So 3");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_3);
            break;
        case "4":
            //alert("So 4");
            return setPro(arrayProduct_4);
            break;
        }
    }

    function setPro(arr)
    {
        function removeOptions(selectbox)
        {
            var i;
            for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                selectbox.remove(i);
            }
        }
        //using the function:
        removeOptions(document.getElementById("pro_name"));

        bbb=arr;
        //alert(bbb);
        var name = document.getElementById("pro_name");

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value",[i]);
            option.text = arr[i];
            name.appendChild(option);
        }

    }

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form class="wrapper-dropdown">
        <h2>Product Style</h2>
            <select id="pro_style" onChange="changeProbyStyle(this.value);">
            </select>
        <h2>Product Name</h2>
            <select id="pro_name">
            </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have edited this entry for documents. Hope my stupid question will be help...

Comment: Does this have anything to do with your tags php and asp.net?

Comment: Sorry I made wrong !!!

Comment: In your `setPro(...)` function you need to clear the `<select>` element before adding new ones. Check this link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364493/how-do-i-clear-all-options-in-a-dropdown-box

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer, and don't put it in the question. Then mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you @TasosK. It's my last day for this task. Your help is very pleasure....

Comment: @j08691 oh please....some guys will use this question to search for solution (I have tried this) so I think that is better. I have mark it as Resovled also....

Comment: That's not how it works here. Please enter your answer below, or delete the question.