# How to create dynamic json in php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I want to display dynamic dependent dropdown list in CI.
I create below dynamic json but I am not understanding how to convert this to php format.

```
{
    "salary": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "text": 2017,
            "data": {},
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "text": "May"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "text": "July"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "text": "August"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "text": "September"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "text": "October"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my PHP code where I want to implement this code.
If `text` = 2017 is same means PAY_YEAR IS SAME then in it will display all months that are in its `children` part.it should be displayed in PAY_MONTH part.

Like: in json we can see 2017 is there and in children part 5 months inside it.
So, if a user will select 2017 from dropdown then in another dropdown of pay_month all months should come.

```
<form action="#" method="get" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group" style="float: left;">
        <label class="control-label">Select Year</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select>
                <?php
                foreach ($salary  as $row) {?>
                <option><?php  echo $row->PAY_YEAR;}?></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Select Month</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select>
                <?php
                foreach ($salary  as $row) {?>
                <option><?php  echo $row->PAY_MONTH;}?></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I hope you guys understand me.

Comment: Why can't you use client side script (javascript/jQuery) for this..?

Comment: i already uused this json for dynamic thing in treeview structure thats why i have to use this

Comment: yes @amit sutar just pass the value to JS and manupulate the Drop-down.. that will be more convinient

Comment: sure i will try this but i dont about javascript much. can you give me some hints or code

Comment: first, fill the year drop down with php.. and while selecting fill initiate AJAX request to get a list of Months and feed it in Months Drop-down

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this.

First add id for both the dropdown.
For year dropdown add id="year_select"
For salary dropdown add id="sal_select"

```js
$("#year_select").change(function() {
 $.getJSON('json_data.txt', function(read_data) {
  var data = read_data.salary[0].children;
  var str_opt = "<option value=''></option>";
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
   str_opt += "<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>"+data[i].id+"</option>";
  });
  $('#sal_select').html(str_opt);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite certain what you are asking, but if you need to convert JSON to PHP variable (turns it into an array) you can use `json_decode($json)` and the other direction `json_encode($variable)`.

[PHP manual reference for decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

[PHP manual reference for encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

**Edit:** Now I see that's not what you are asking. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232146/dynamically-populating-drop-down-list-from-selection-of-another-drop-down-value) will help, except using a `XMLHttpRequest` in the `changecat(value)` function like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp).