# How to populate 3 dropdown boxes and 1 input box based on my array? HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need help figuring the code in my fiddle. I have 3 dropdown boxes and 1 input box. What I want to do is,

> Box 1: Show the brand
>
> Box 2: Show the model based on brand
>
> Box 3: Parts available for repair (screen, battery, etc... it varies
>   depends on the brand)
>
> Box 4: Inputbox that shows the price.

Every phone part has its own price, so it should only populate the input box with the price once the brand, model, and the part has been selected.

So basically, when you select Apple -> iPhone 5 -> Screen, the input box should display the price for the screen, and so on...

I just cant figure out how to make this right.

I had to show a code in order to attach a fiddle.

```
<select name="devicelist" id="devicelist" style="width:350px;" onchange="changecat1(this.value);">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Brand</option>
      <option value="A">Apple</option>
      <option value="B">Blackberry</option>
      <option value="G">Google</option>
      <option value="H">Huawei</option>
      <option value="L">LG</option>
      <option value="M">Motorola</option>
      <option value="S">Samsung</option>
    </select>
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Foxseiz/modjzqwn/28/).

Comment: Updated the fiddle, cleaned the html a bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically Populating Drop down list from selection of another drop down value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232146/dynamically-populating-drop-down-list-from-selection-of-another-drop-down-value)

Comment: @divy3993 I can only make that work on 2 dropdown boxes, unfortunately.

Comment: You may think it is an overkill but if you choose to build this simple form with Vue.js you will be surprised how easy it is.

Comment: @Foxseiz I have created one [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/1bwh0s8r/) for you. Could you please check it and tell me if anything wrong ?

Comment: jaydeep, this is awesome, but how to clear input when you selected another brand? I have updated my fiddle also to change the Samsung parts but it doesn't matter anymore I guess.

Comment: @JaydeepMor please add it as the answer so I can mark it. thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you @JaydeepMor, I figured out which line is missing thats why its not clearing the input. figured out that I have to add the updatePrice(); in the updateDrp.

Comment: Okay. Tomorrow I will post it with more optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will answer your question

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#type").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "A") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test1'>iPhone</option><option value='test2'>iPhone2</option>");
        } else if (val == "B") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test2'>Blackberry1</option><option value='test2'>Blackberry2</option>");
        } else if (val == "C") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test3'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "") {
            $("#size").html("<option value=''>--select one--</option>");
        }
    });
    
     $("#size").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "test1") {
            $("#khind").html("<option value='test1'>Screen</option><option value='test2'>Battery</option>");
        } else if (val == "test2") {
            $("#khind").html("<option value='test2'>Front Camera</option><option value='test2'>back Front Camera</option>");
        } else if (val == "test3") {
            $("#khind").html("<option value='test3'>glass</option><option value='test2'>housing</option>");
        } else if (val == "item0") {
            $("#khind").html("<option value=''>--select one--</option>");
        }
    });
    
    $("#khind").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "test1") {
            $("#price").html("<option value='test1'>$189.00</option><option value='test2'>$19.00</option>");
        } else if (val == "test2") {
            $("#price").html("<option value='test2'>$189.00</option><option value='test2'>$189.00</option>");
        } else if (val == "test3") {
            $("#price").html("<option value='test3'>$189.00</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "") {
            $("#price").html("<option value=''>--select one--</option>");
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="type">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Brand</option>
  <option value="A">Apple</option>
  <option value="B">Blackberry</option>
  <option value="G">Google</option>
  <option value="H">Huawei</option>
  <option value="L">LG</option>
  <option value="M">Motorola</option>
  <option value="S">Samsung</option>
</select>

<select id="size">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>

<select id="khind">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>

<select id="price">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, the 4th box should be an input box(disabled) and every phone part has their specific price.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is that this should be for people who want to check how much would be the repair price for their device.