# How to display info from other sheets, specific to text in cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

Our company works at different properties repairing appliances, I would like to build a database to search up the information on each appliance at specific properties and in their specific apt/units, I created a form to start this process, but I need help with some complex coding.

I first created a box for the property, then I created an "Apt/Unit" box. The idea is when I select a property, the units tied to that property are shown in dropdown/type searchable list in the Apt/Unit box.

I then created an "Appliance type" box. The idea is when the "Apt/Unit" is selected, it will display the dropdown/type searchable list of the appliances tied to that specific "Apt/Unit".

Then I created boxes for the info for the appliance (Brand, Model #, Serial #, & Color), this is a bit more self-explanatory - once the appliance type is selected, it will display the respective information for each box for that appliance.

Here's the link to the Google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JZhEYjk5xVN3uOc_Ucb8HFr6d96XQ2Q_ehAd-d_o0ME/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Something alike is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232146/dynamically-populating-drop-down-list-from-selection-of-another-drop-down-value

Comment: But actually the task looks exactly like applying the filters. First you filter you table by first column (Property), then by next column (Apt/Unit), then by next column, etc. Until you have just one row (or several rows). Have you tried to filter the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is third variant of the script:

```
// global variables
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var SHEET_USERFACE = SS.getSheetByName('Userface');
var SHEET_DATA = SS.getSheetByName('Data');

function onLoad() { reset() }

function reset() {
  SS.toast('Please wait...');

  SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c9:c21').clearContent();
  SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c9:c13').clearDataValidations();

  var obj = make_obj_from_data();
  update_menu_prop(obj);
  update_menu_unit(obj);
  update_menu_type(obj);

  SS.toast('The sheet has been reset');
}

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Userface') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 3) return;

  // Property menu
  if (e.range.rowStart == 9) {
    e.source.toast('Please, wait...');
    SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c11:c21').clearContent();
    SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c11:c13').clearDataValidations();
    var obj = make_obj_from_data();
    update_menu_unit(obj);
    update_menu_type(obj);
    e.source.toast('The sheet has been updated');
  }

  // Apt/Unit menu
  if (e.range.rowStart == 11) {
    e.source.toast('Please, wait...');
    SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c13:c21').clearContent();
    SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c13').clearDataValidations();
    var obj = make_obj_from_data();
    update_menu_type(obj);
    e.source.toast('The sheet has been updated');
  }

  // Applicance type menu
  if (e.range.rowStart == 13) {
    e.source.toast('Please, wait...');
    SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c15:c21').clearContent();
    var obj = make_obj_from_data();
    update_brand_model_serial_color(obj);
    e.source.toast('The sheet has been updated');
  }
  
}

function make_obj_from_data() {
  var data = SHEET_DATA.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
  var obj = {};

  for (let row of data) {
    var [prop, unit, type, ...etc] = row;
    try { 
      obj[prop][unit][type] = etc;
    }
    catch(e) { 
      try {
        obj[prop][unit] = {}; obj[prop][unit][type] = etc;
      }
      catch(e) {
        obj[prop] = {}; obj[prop][unit] = {}; obj[prop][unit][type] = etc;
      }
    }
  }

  return obj;
}

function update_menu_prop(obj) {
  var cell = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c9');
  try {
    var list = Object.keys(obj);
    set_data_validation(cell, list);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('update_menu_prop(obj)');
    console.log(e);
  } 
}

function update_menu_unit(obj) {
  var prop = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c9').getValue();
  var cell = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c11');
  try {
    var list = Object.keys(obj[prop]);
    set_data_validation(cell, list);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('update_menu_unit(obj)');
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function update_menu_type(obj) {
  var prop = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c9').getValue();
  var unit = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c11').getValue();
  var cell = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c13');
  try {
    var list = Object.keys(obj[prop][unit]);
    set_data_validation(cell, list);
    if (list.length == 1) update_brand_model_serial_color(obj)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('update_menu_type(obj)');
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function update_brand_model_serial_color(obj) {
  var [prop,,unit,,type] = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c9:c13').getValues();
  try {
    var [brand, model, serial, color] = obj[prop][unit][type];
    var arr = [[brand],[''],[model],[''],[serial],[''],[color]];
    SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c15:c21').setValues(arr);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('update_brand_model_serial_color(obj)');
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function set_data_validation(cell, list) {
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  // put the value in the cell if there is just one element in the list
  if (list.length == 1) cell.setValue(list[0]);
}
```

[Here is my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gh9Gx62LJeHCepvKm2C3ZYnM3mGGh52qAEFTM2crxps/edit?usp=sharing).

It works about that way as it does any similar interface. You select the first menu and it changes data validation for the second menu and cleans the third menu. Then you select the second menu and it changes the third one. As soon as you change the third menu it fills the rest fields.

Since you're using just the three menus and they supposed to be changed step by step I decided to 'hardcode' them. It's not the best practice and there can be problems if/when you decide to change the functionality. But for this particular case I think the 'hardcoding' is forgivable. It works relatively fast and the code is relatively readable.

Comment: Hey Yuri! Just asked for permission on this google sheet!

Comment: This one is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much. If you have a PayPal or etc. please feel free to share it.

Comment: Thank you. It was my pleasure. I didn't mean to receive any payments. And unfortunately now I live in the fascist a belligerent state which have no PayPal or any other decent payment system anymore. It's a bit surprising that we still have access to Stackoverflow. Not sure if it will last long. :(

Comment: Well, when you do - please reach out to me, may I have your email for future reference?

Comment: I just answered you via email if you don't mind. Let's stay in touch.

Answer (score 2):

non-scripted solution:

```
=IFERROR({INDEX(IFERROR(Data!A1:G1/0)); Data!A1:G1; QUERY({Data!A2:G}, "where 1=1 "&
 IF(C10="",,"and lower(Col1) contains '"&LOWER(C10)&"'")&
 IF(C12="",,"and Col2 = "&C12)&
 IF(C14="",,"and lower(Col3) contains '"&LOWER(C14)&"'")&
 IF(C16="",,"and lower(Col4) contains '"&LOWER(C16)&"'")&
 IF(C18="",,"and lower(Col5) contains '"&LOWER(C18)&"'")&
 IF(C20="",,"and lower(Col6) contains '"&LOWER(C20)&"'")&
 IF(C22="",,"and lower(Col7) contains '"&LOWER(C22)&"'"), 0)}, {"";"no data"})
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11vBzyf4qOmovlgXJLaTy_tSQDcXIc_TEMQzjwrrP3Og/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Well, I suspect this is a better solution for the real life. The native functions work much faster than any server script. And actually I think there could be one more solution (probably the best one) via the HTML side panel and a client side script.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I've made it. But this is overkill:

```
// global variables
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var SHEET_USERFACE = SS.getSheetByName('Userface');
var SHEET_DATA = SS.getSheetByName('Data');

function onLoad() { reset() }

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Userface') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 3) return;
  if (![9,11,13,15,17,19,21].includes(e.range.rowStart)) return;
  e.source.toast('Please, wait...');
  set_filter(e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue(), e.value);
  set_all_menus();
  e.source.toast('The sheet has been updated');
}

function reset() {
  SS.toast('Please wait...');
  try { SHEET_DATA.getFilter().remove() } catch(e) {}
  SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c9:c21').clearContent().clearDataValidations();
  set_all_menus();
  SS.toast('The sheet has been updated');
}

function set_all_menus() {
  var data = SHEET_DATA.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().filter((_,i) => !SHEET_DATA.isRowHiddenByFilter(i+1));

  set_menu(data, 'b9',  'c9');
  set_menu(data, 'b11', 'c11');
  set_menu(data, 'b13', 'c13');
  set_menu(data, 'b15', 'c15');
  set_menu(data, 'b17', 'c17');
  set_menu(data, 'b19', 'c19');
  set_menu(data, 'b21', 'c21');
}

function set_menu(data, title, cell) {
  var menu_title = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange(title).getValue();
  var menu_cell = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange(cell);
  var col_index = data[0].indexOf(menu_title);
  var menu_list = [...new Set([...data.map(e => e[col_index])])].slice(1);
  var menu_rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(menu_list).build();
  menu_cell.setDataValidation(menu_rule);
}

function set_filter(column_title, value) {

  // get all the data and col index
  var [header, ...data] = SHEET_DATA.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col_index = header.indexOf(column_title);

  // unhide all values of the given column
  var clear = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues([]).build();
  var range = SHEET_DATA.getDataRange();
  var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter()
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(col_index+1, clear);

  // get the values to hide
  var col_data = data.map(e => e[col_index]);
  var filtered = col_data.filter( (e, i) => e != value && SHEET_DATA.isRowHiddenByFilter(i+1) );
  var to_hide = col_data.filter( e => e != value );
  var hidden = [...new Set([...filtered, ...to_hide])];
  
  // hide the values with the filter
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(hidden).build();
  var range = SHEET_DATA.getDataRange();
  var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter()
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(col_index+1, criteria);
}
```

[image]

[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AVlvITHG0IXnGaJ-LfW4grrJdSZsBt96NO6FYo5w00c/edit?usp=sharing).

It works quite slow. I'd propose to use the native filters instead. Basically the script turns on and off the filters an changes data validation for the dropdown menus respectively.

---

**Update**

Here another version of the script. It works much faster but it uses the 'helper sheet' to store temporary data (the filtered table). You can hide the 'helper sheet' if you want.

```
// global variables
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var SHEET_USERFACE = SS.getSheetByName('Userface');
var SHEET_DATA = SS.getSheetByName('Data');
var SHEET_HELPER = SS.getSheetByName('Helper'); // the hidden sheet with temp data
var PROPERTY_LIST = [...new Set(SHEET_DATA.getRange('a2:a').getValues().flat())]; // 'Property' list
var DATA_OBJ = {}; 

function onLoad() { reset() }

function onEdit(e) {
  var {range, source, value} = e;

  if (range.getSheet().getName() != 'Userface') return;
  if (range.columnStart != 3) return;
  if (![9,11,13,15,17,19,21].includes(range.rowStart)) return;

  source.toast('Please, wait...');

  // reset whenever the first menu is changing
  if (range.rowStart == 9) {
    reset();
    source.getRange('c9').setValue(value);
  }

  var col_header = range.offset(0,-1).getValue();

  update_sheet_helper(col_header, value);
  update_all_dropdown_menus();
  
  source.toast('The sheet has been updated');
}

function reset() {
  SS.toast('Please wait...');

  // copy data from SHEET_DATA to SHEET_HELPER
  SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('c9:c21').clearContent().clearDataValidations();
  SHEET_DATA.getDataRange().copyTo(SHEET_HELPER.clearContents().getRange(1,1));

  update_data_obj();
  update_all_dropdown_menus();

  SS.toast('The sheet has been updated');
}

// make DATA_OBJECT from SHEET_HELPER
function update_data_obj() {
  DATA_OBJ = {};
  var [header, ...data] = SHEET_HELPER.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (let i in header) DATA_OBJ[header[i]] = data.map(e => e[i]);
  DATA_OBJ['Property'] = PROPERTY_LIST; // let 'Property' list will be full always
}

// remove from SHEET_DATA_HELPER all the rows
// that have no given value in column with given title
function update_sheet_helper(col_title, value) {
  var [header, ...data] = SHEET_HELPER.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col_index = header.indexOf(col_title);
  data = data.filter(k => k[col_index] == value);
  var table = [header, ...data];
  SHEET_HELPER.clearContents().getRange(1,1,table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);
  update_data_obj();
}

function update_all_dropdown_menus() {
  SHEET_USERFACE.getRange('b9:c21').getValues().forEach((row,i) => {
      if (row[0] != '') set_data_validation(DATA_OBJ[row[0]], 'c' + (i+9));
    });

  function set_data_validation(data, cell_address) {
    var menu_list = [...new Set([...data])]; // remove duplicates from the array
    var menu_rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(menu_list).build();
    var cell_range = SHEET_USERFACE.getRange(cell_address)
    cell_range.setDataValidation(menu_rule);
    if (menu_list.length == 1) cell_range.setValue(menu_list[0]);
  }
}
```

[The sheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rea4vMV8V0_ruyS6x_V5lmLOlm0I5pOPoJ4-Ijn9SaU/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: This is perfect, the only thing that I noticed is when I selected a property, and try to pick another property - it appears it deleted the other one so I can't select anything

Comment: It's need to click the round 'Clear' button if you want to select another item in the same list. Filters work this way.

Comment: I just got an idea how it can be done another way. It should work much faster I hope. I'll try to rewrite the code soon.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I really appreciate this.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It works faster since it doesn't use filters. It uses the additional sheet ('Helper') to store the temp data.

Comment: I just requested access to see the form, so I can have the button option as well!

Comment: This is perfect Yuri, exactly what I wanted to achieve. For the "Brand, Model, Serial, Color" would it be possible not to have the drop-down arrows on those boxes? Only because once the appliance is selected, those boxes automatically display the information associated to that appliance, so it's unnecessary to have the arrows.

Comment: Okay. I've removed the data validation from the last four cells.

Comment: Thanks! Now the only other bug I noticed was you can't select another appliance in the same unit, for example - if I choose a refrigerator, and it generates the info, I can't try and select another appliance in the same unit, it only displays the one I already selected, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: This is not a bug. This is the way how the filters work in this implementation. Probably it can be done another way. I will think tomorrow. It's quite late already at my place.

Comment: Ah got it. Really appreciate the help! Have a good night!

Comment: Hi, I just added another answer since there is the code based on the whole nother approach. It's less universal but it works better.