# Fastest way to replace big drop down list in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, internet-explorer

I have to manage big drop down list (thousands of items) and I encounter performance problem with IE8 with the jQuery .html method.
Indeed it takes 3-4seconds to clear the content.

Do you have any workarounds ?

Code :

```
var selectHtml = "";
$(data.items).each(function () {

    var option = "<option value='";
    option += this.Value + "'";

    if (this.Selected) {
        option += " selected";
    }

    option += ">" + this.Text + "</option>";
    selectHtml += option;
});
$(target).html(selectHtml);
```

.html of jQuery call .empty and in the IE profiler I can see that it is .empty that takes most of the time.

Comment: try .empty() method for clearing the html

Comment: Maybe using a Typeahead search where items are loaded in via AJAX should be a consideration over loading thousands of `<option>` elements

Comment: Can you not split the list up, and use an additional filter so the list isn't so big? It would probably be more user friendly?

Comment: Revised answer below  - try and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23552898/1431524

I ended up with this code :

```
function clearOptions(select) {
    var selectParentNode = select.parentNode;
    if (selectParentNode) {
        var newSelect = select.cloneNode(false); // Make a shallow copy
        selectParentNode.replaceChild(newSelect, select);
        return newSelect;
    }
    return undefined;
}

function appendSelectHtml(data, target) {
    var selectHtml = [];
    $(data.items).each(function () {
        var selected = this.Selected ? ' selected' : '';
        var option = "<option value='" + this.Value + "'" + selected + ">" + this.Text + "</option>";
        selectHtml.push(option);
    });
    target = $(clearOptions(target[0])); //The item that was contained in the selector isn't in the DOM anymore
    target.append(selectHtml.join(""));       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean something like

```
<ul id='mylist'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  .... 
  <li>Item n</li>
</ul>
```

or the equivalent `select`/`option` statement, you need:

```
$('#mylist').empty()
```

Alternatively, if you're only actually changing a few items in your dropdown list, perhaps you should maintain a map between the data.value and the element in the select list, so you only need to add items which have not already been placed in the list, and have a simple reference to items to remove.

I suspect you are wrong about the time split and most of the time is building the list. Try pushing all your new option items onto an array and then performing a single join of the array at the end.

```
var list = [];

$(data.items).each(function () {
    var selected = this.Selected ? ' selected' : '';
    var option = "<option value='" + this.Value + "'" + selected + ">" 
                 + this.Text + "</option>";
    list.push( option);
});

$(target).html(list.join( "\n"));
```

Comment: The array increased slightly the performance. 
Maintain a map would be another solution perfectly viable, thanks !

Comment: If data.items is an array and not an object, you can use: `list = data.items.map( function () ....);` instead of your each loop