# How to clear the dropdown value using Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript in my application. I want to clear the dropdown list values.

Typescript:-

```
  let myContainer = document.getElementById('date') as HTMLInputElement;
  myContainer.value = "";
```

By using the above code, I can able to clear the dropdown list value. But I cannot able to clear the value selected in the dropdown popup. How to achieve that in typescript?

Comment: Do you want to clear a `select` list or and `input` because you are declaring `myContainer as HTMLInputElement`? In any other case, you do it the same way as with JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364493/how-do-i-clear-all-options-in-a-dropdown-box

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript. You can't clear a dropdown list (assuming you mean a plain old HTML `<select>` element. The closest you can come is to have the first item be something like "Choose city...", and select that.