# Assign Variable to option value

Tags: javascript

I want to remove option from a selected dropdown, for this I've made removeValue() function but is not working as expected.

I debug the code and found that **[value=removeid]**. Var removeid is not working as expected here.

JavaScript function removeValue

```
function removeValue() {
  var removeid = $('#transaction_user_account_id').val() 
  alert(removeid); // I am getting my ID here
  $("#transaction_transfer_account_id option[value=removeid]").remove();
 };
```

If I give a constant value like **value="21"**, then is working properly but when I assign my Var removeid to option[Value=removeid]. It stops working.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why do you expect a variable to be expanded inside a string?

Comment: This link seems to be the answer of your question.
[Clear all options from Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364493/how-do-i-clear-all-options-in-a-dropdown-box) Th

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using `removeid` as string, not as a variable. Try this instead:

```
$("#transaction_transfer_account_id option[value=" + removeid + "]").remove();
```

Or you want to be all fancy-pants ES6 use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
$(`#transaction_transfer_account_id option[value="${removeid}"]`).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#transaction_transfer_account_id option[value=removeid]").remove();
```

the above statement seems to be wrong.

'removeid' is a variable here, but in above statement its not been treated as same. it should be rewritten as

```
$("#transaction_transfer_account_id option[value=" + removeid + "]").remove();
```