# Can't order select options by value

Tags: javascript, html

I have trouble reordering the options within a select box by value, from lowest to highest programatically. Whatever I have tried continues to order the list alphabetically, and I cannot find a way to control it based by the value.

The select field in question:

```
<select class="jet-select__control" name="koncert-dag">
        
    <option value="" data-label="VÆLG DAG" data-counter-prefix="(" data-counter-suffix=")">VÆLG DAG</option>
        <option value="42" data-label="Fredag" data-counter-prefix="(" data-counter-suffix=")">Fredag</option>
        <option value="43" data-label="Lørdag" data-counter-prefix="(" data-counter-suffix=")">Lørdag</option>
        <option value="44" data-label="Søndag" data-counter-prefix="(" data-counter-suffix=")">Søndag</option>
        <option value="41" data-label="Torsdag" data-counter-prefix="(" data-counter-suffix=")">Torsdag</option>
</select>
```

My boss ordered this done in a brick builder (Elementor / Wordpress) which prohibits me from just arranging it like I usually would (annoying). So I am trying to force it into the order of 41 - 44 with JavaScript. My best bet is this line of code, which only flips it upside down so 41 is first, followed by 44, 43, 42.

```
<script>
const setId = document.querySelector('.jet-select__control');

setId.setAttribute('id', 'reorder-list');

 
window.onload = function sortOptions() {
    var options = document.getElementById('reorder-list').options;
    var optionsArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        optionsArray.push(options[i]);
    }
    optionsArray = optionsArray.sort(function (a, b) {           
        return a.HTMLSelectElement.options.charCodeAt(0) - b.HTMLSelectElement.options.charCodeAt(0);    
    });

    for (var i = 0; i <= options.length; i++) {
        options[i] = optionsArray[i];
    }
    options[0].selected = true;
}

sortOptions();
    
</script>
```

Is there a way to make it use the values instead? Or just through JavaScript simply force it to do a certain order that I define?

Comment: So why are you sorting your options by the first character of their innerHTML content then, when you said you wanted to sort them by the content of their value attribute?

Comment: I can't for the life of me find the selector for targeting the options

Comment: `HTMLSelectElement.options` returns a read-only list, so your attempt to modify the options using `options[i] =  ...` most likely won't work. And the ID you are using to try and find your select element, does not appear to be set on the element?

Comment: Correct, the ID is injected before : 
const setId = document.querySelector('.jet-select__control');

setId.setAttribute('id', 'reorder-list');

Should have put that in the question as well, I can see the confusion

Hm, if not through options[i], how would I get around it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55897038/1427878

Comment: Hmm, that one creates new options - but it's possible to inject it as metadata into existing options instead, or?

Comment: You said this was about ordering the options, so at what point would that require any additional "meta data"?

Comment: The link you referred to was a post about creating new options within the selection - Im not sure how to incorporate that information into the problem Im having!

Comment: The important part in there is the appending of the options to the select field. Whether you create new options, or use your already existing ones, doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: So Ill need to append 42-44 after 41 I reckon? I'm very lost in this by now sadly, a bit out of my JS scope

Comment: You sort your options first, and then you loop over that sorted collection, and append them one by one. After clearing the existing options first.