# Django forms - limiting options from fields based on the answer of another field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light, django-smart-selects

I have a Django form that receives entries from the users with information on a surgical procedure. Each Procedure will have only one (surgical) Technique and only one Diagnosis. Each Technique may be related to a limited number of Diagnosis, and each Diagnosis may be used on different Techniques. I want to limit which Diagnosis appear of the form based on which Technique the user selected previously on the form.

I tried using smart_selects ChainedManyToMany field with relative success, but it enable multiple Diagnosis to be selected, I only want to have one.

I`m also using DAL for autocompleting the Technique (over 1,6k options) as the user types.

My models:

```
# The "Technique" model
class Sigtap(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=175, default='')


# The "Diagnosis" model
class Cid10(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=270, default='')
    sigtap_compativel = models.ManyToManyField(Sigtap, blank=True)


# The "Surgical Procedure" model
class Cirurgia(models.Model):
    paciente = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Número do prontuário')
    data = models.DateField(verbose_name='Data de realização')
    procedimento = models.ForeignKey(Sigtap, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     verbose_name='Código do procedimento (SIGTAP)')
    cid = ChainedManyToManyField(
        Cid10, horizontal=True, chained_field='procedimento', chained_model_field='sigtap_compativel', auto_choose=True, verbose_name='CID-10')
```

My forms:

```
class CirurgiaModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cirurgia
        fields = ['paciente', 'data', 'procedimento', 'cid']
        widgets = {
            'procedimento': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='sigtap-autocomplete'),
        }
```

How can I get the form field to show only the Diagnosis related to the Technique selected and allow only one option?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Edited, hope it’s clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of naming fields and classes confused me **a lot**, because the name of the classes does not represent what they really are...and also there is this:

```
procedimento = models.ForeignKey(Sigtap, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     verbose_name='Código do procedimento (SIGTAP)')
```

where you change the name I don't know for what reason, if you are going with codes like `cid` and `sigtap` just stick with it. Really bad practice overall.

Anyway, what you need is to use [AJAX](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) to send a request to a view where you filter a `Model` based on a given `id`, then use that data back in the template. I was not able to fit this solution into a `ModelForm` because of the nature of the relationship (will need to look into that) so instead I used a `<select>` tag inside the HTML form:

forms.py:

```
class CirurgiaModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    procedimento = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sigtap.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select({'onchange' : "myFunction(this.value);"}))

    class Meta:
        model = Cirurgia
        fields = ['paciente', 'data', 'procedimento']
        widgets = {
          'data': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def surgery(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CirurgiaModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                cid = Cid10.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('cid'))
                cirurgia = Cirurgia.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
                cirurgia.cid.add(cid)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass

            return redirect('/surgery/')

    else:
        form = CirurgiaModelForm()
    
    return render(request, 'surgery.html', {'form': form})

def filter_diagnosis_ajax(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    procedimento = Sigtap.objects.get(id=data['technique_id'])
    cid_list = list(Cid10.objects.filter(sigtap_compativel=procedimento).values())
    return JsonResponse({'diagnoses': cid_list})
```

surgery.html ([populate select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674667/7100120), [clear select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364546/7100120))

```
{% block content %}
<form action="surgery/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <label>diagnosis: </label><select name="cid" id="id_cid"></select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" >Create Procedure</button>
</form>

<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    function removeOptions(selectElement) {
        var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
        for(i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
            selectElement.remove(i);
        }
    }

    function myFunction(value) {
        url = '/filter/technique/'
        const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            mode: 'same-origin',
            body: JSON.stringify({'technique_id': value}),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            var diagnosis_select = document.getElementById("id_cid");
            removeOptions(diagnosis_select);
            for (var i = 0; i<=data.diagnoses.length-1; i++){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = data.diagnoses[i]['id'];
                opt.innerHTML = data.diagnoses[i]['descricao'];
                diagnosis_select.appendChild(opt);
            }
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was already using django-autocomplete-light I managed to do it with little modifications on [Django Autocomplete Light Documentation](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).